Invalid or missing Authorization header- Glossary Creation
This is DeepL's api for creating glossaries: https://developers.deepl.com/docs/api-reference/glossaries/openapi-spec-for-glossary-management
Under the documentation, I should be able to set an authorization header, and send a body of texts to be added to a glossary.
I am still using postman as I am probing my possibilities, but can't get it to work. I get met with a "Invalid or missing Authorization header" response. I am able to use my authorization key to do normal translation, but not glossary creation. (I have pro account)
I tried:

Sending a POST request at https://api.deepl.com/v2/glossaries
Adding an API key under authorization, setting the key to "DeepL-Auth-Key" and the value to my API key
Adding a auth_key query containing my authorization key
Add a body just as the example was given

Am I missing something? If my body was bad I'd be getting another error, but am currently clueless since there weren't many questions in regards to this.

"Adding an API key under authorization, setting the key to "DeepL-Auth-Key" and the value to my API key"
This sounds wrong, the Authorization header is part of the HTTP standard and needs to be set to "DeepL-Auth-Key ", so e.g. "DeepL-Auth-Key 123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000"

There is also a postman collection by DeepL https://www.postman.com/deepl-api/workspace/deepl-api-developers

@Gaze the collection you mentioned work for me. Thank you so much

I could able to create glossary using postman. Now how can I use it in my application? I have developed interface like deepl where user can translate text and document. I have one subscription for it. so using this application and one subscription my employee can use deepl.


The official DeepL postman collection is here
As I stated in the comment, I think your authorization was wrong. The HTTP header Authorization needs to be set to DeepL-Auth-Key <yourAuthKey>
You can translate using a glossary by passing a glossary_id parameter with your translate request, see the docs (there is an Example call (with glossary))

